# Why is a model of the secret Starship in plain view?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-into-darkness

Why is a model of the dreadnought class Starship in Star Trek Into Darkness in plain view. I thought it was supposed to be a classified project?

In the below scene it is in clear view on the Admiral Alexander Marcus's desk.

[image: dreadnought class Starship]

In [memory-alpha.wikia , USS Vengeance](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Vengeance) it even states this, but there is not an explanation?

Comment: Without an indication of scale, it could just be a large model of a smaller ship.

Comment: Indeed, it is clear that the *Phoenix* and *Kelvin* models are not on the same scale.

Comment: @Politank-Z, are not the other two models  NX-class Enterprise and the USS Kelvin? Still, all evidence points to that being the USS Vengeance.

Comment: @Richard, see my above comment. Cheers.

Comment: On the Memory Alpha page you link to, an out-of-universe explanation is given in that Roberto Orci said it was a mistake that he would have prevented, had he been on set when the scene was filmed.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, I saw that, but the fact it was ultimately put in is still unanswered. But, that very well could be the final answer, that it was just a plain mistake.

Comment: @KyloRen On magnifying the image, I also see the NX Class vessel, but I'm pretty sure that the model to its right is the *Phoenix*. I'm not saying that the model to the left isn't dreadnought class, only that the other models don't provide the scale to indicate the size and significance of the dreadnought model. It may resemble another, smaller, publicly known class of ship.

Comment: Additionally, the Dreadnought Class may have been public knowledge, while some aspect of The Vengeance itself was secret.

Comment: @Politank-Z According to [the model manufacturers](http://qmxonline.com/products/cinema-arts-history-of-starflight-gallery), left-to-right is the *Vengeance*, the *Kelvin*, the NX-01 *Enterprise*, and the NX Alpha. You can just see the nose cone of the *Phoenix* on the far right of Kylo's image

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was addressed by the film's writer, [Bob Orci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roberto_Orci). The short answer was that it was (out-of-universe) a production goof and (in-universe) justified by making the model an experimental design, itself based on a pre-existing non-military design which wouldn't have seemed out of place on the desk of a Starfleet Admiral *tasked with overseeing ship construction.*

> **Q.**  *One thing I didn’t get, and maybe Bob can shine light on this, **why did Marcus have a model of his secret ship on display in his office?** Not very subtle...*
>
> **Bob Orci:**   *Agree that was a mistake — shoulda been on set that day!*
> *However, **one could argue that a pre-existing design was
> recommissioned and altered to be a weapon of war.***
>
> <sub><sup>[TrekMovie.com - Into Darkness Second Week + Polls](http://trekmovie.com/2013/05/28/into-darkness-second-week-polls/#comment-5118458)</sup></sub>

Comment: Nice find , up vote for that one!!!